# Unable to install hw params usb xmos and alsa

Tags: sound, alsa

Still having trouble getting my xmos card to work, after updating to the latest kernel my card appeared as a snd-usb-audio device and is listed in `aplay -l`

I have set it to be the first card in options in `alsa-base.conf`

I have the following in `asound.conf`:

```
pcm.!default {
type hw
card 0
}
ctl.!default {
type hw
card 0
}
```

But it will not play audio

```
sudo aplay -D plughw:0,0 /media/Disk2/Rehab.flac
[sudo] password for stu:
Playing raw data '/media/Disk2/Rehab.flac' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1297: Unable to install hw params:
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  U8
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 8
FRAME_BITS: 8
CHANNELS: 1
RATE: 8000
PERIOD_TIME: 125000
PERIOD_SIZE: 1000
PERIOD_BYTES: 1000
PERIODS: 4
BUFFER_TIME: 500000
BUFFER_SIZE: NONE
BUFFER_BYTES: 4000
TICK_TIME: 0
```

My alsa config is here:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=3d3a11fb80ca467d9922fdfd58f5320f103726b2

Any ideas?

#### Update 1

Also, `dmesg` produces:

```
 usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[79121.642479] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=20b1, idProduct=000a
[79121.642487] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[79121.642492] usb 3-1: Product: xCORE USB Audio 2.0
[79121.642496] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: XMOS
[79121.657970] snd-usb-audio 3-1:1.0: cannot find the slot for index 0 (range 0-        1), error: -16
[79121.658044] usb 3-1: cannot create card instance 0
[79121.658088] snd-usb-audio: probe of 3-1:1.0 failed with error -5
[79121.658121] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[79271.693734] usbcore: deregistering interface driver snd-usb-audio
[79276.863389] usb 3-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex         = 0xa00, type = 4
[79276.863490] usb 3-1: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[79276.863759] usb 3-1: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex         = 0xa00, type = 4
[79276.863859] usb 3-1: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
```

Is there anyway to give it more generic parameters?

#### Update 2

Thanks, I've converted a file to 48Khz wav but still get errors:

```
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:998:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) unable to install hw params
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1034:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
aplay: main:722: audio open error: Input/output error
```

I even ran a Live CD with Ubuntu desktop to make my life easier but Alsa kept giving errors messages. Is there anything I can do about the hw parameters?

Comment: Stuart, you're *answering* your question instead of *[edit]ing* it...  The more "answers" you give, the less likely you'll find people to *actually answer* your question, so **please** delete your "answers" and add them to your question!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Using the `hw` device disables all automatic sample format conversions.
(And `aplay` does not support FLAC files.)

The correct way to set the default card in `asound.conf` would be this:

```perl
defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.ctl.card 0
```

However, card zero is the default one anyway; you don't need any `asound.conf`.